# How to make dropdown content get over content?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I can't see the contents in dropdown because another content is over them (i have iframe down and it covers the data of dropdown contents), i've tried to change the z-index to bigger values and set the position to relative but none of them works, the data in dropdowns are taken from another file:

```css
#Menu-bar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color:black;
  opacity: 0.7;
  filter:alpha (opacity=70);
}

li {
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
}

li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 200;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  z-index: 200;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

#dropdownFollowing:hover .dropdown-content  {
  display: block;    
}
```

```html
<div id="Menu-bar">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="active"  href="MainPage.php">
        <img src="images/comp4.png" alt="">BIO
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="active" id="report-print"></a>
    </li>
    <li id="dropdownFollowing">
      <a class="dropbtn"></a>
      <div class="dropdown-content" id="contentFollow"></div>
    </li>
    <li id="dropdownFollowing">
      <a class="dropbtn"></a>
      <div class="dropdown-content" id="contentMessages"></div>
    </li>
    <li id="dropdownFollowing">
      <a class="dropbtn" id="notf"></a>
      <div class="dropdown-content" id="contentNotifications"></div>
    </li>
    <li style="float: right">
      <a href="logout.php" id="logoutt" class="active"><img src="images/logout.png" alt=""></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure exactly what you are trying to do, 
but to me it seems you cant see the content of the dropdowns because there is no content in them.

https://jsfiddle.net/0jjdzhm9/

```
<div id="Menu-bar">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="active"  href="MainPage.php">
        <img src="images/comp4.png" alt="">BIO
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="active" id="report-print"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdownFollowing">
      <a class="dropbtn">test</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content" id="contentFollow">test</div>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdownFollowing">
      <a class="dropbtn">test</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content" id="contentMessages">test</div>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdownFollowing">
      <a class="dropbtn" id="notf">Test</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content" id="contentNotifications">Test</div>
    </li>
    <li style="float: right">
      <a href="logout.php" id="logoutt" class="active"><img src="images/logout.png" alt=""></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

#Menu-bar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color:black;
  opacity: 0.7;
  filter:alpha (opacity=70);
}

li {
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
}

li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 200;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  z-index: 200;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdownFollowing:hover .dropdown-content  { 
  display: block;    
}
```

also changed the #dropdownFollowing selector to a class (.dropdownFollowing:hover) as you have more than one using it.